# Get contract's owner address without openzeppelin Ownable

Tags: solidity

I want to know if Ethereum stores the contract's deployer address by default.

I know Ownable Library which stores owner's address in a storage variable. I want to know if Ethereum blockchain stores this address too in deployment transaction.
If so, how can i access this information from truffle tests ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

When someone deploys a contract on Ethereum (or any EVM-based blockchain) they are making a transaction not entirely unlike a regular transaction between two addresses (just with a lot of extra data). Just like any regular transaction is stored on the blockchain, so is a deployment. The deployer is the "from" address, so to speak.

Getting this address wouldn't be a function in Truffle, though. You'd need to scrape the blockchain using whichever library you use for interacting with the blockchain, though I am not sure exactly how to do this.

More to the point, if you are talking about accessing this data in Truffle tests, you should have an easier option - you will be deploying the contracts inside the test suite, so you should have the address natively available. For example, if you used:

```js
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
const deployer = accounts[0];
```

and used `deployer` to deploy your contracts in the tests, then you should have the address locally.

Another point worth mentioning: the `Ownable` contracts from OpenZeppelin do not necessarily store the *deployer* of the contract in the `owner` storage variable. While the default is that the deployer is set as the `owner` at deploy, this can be changed afterwards (that's the point of the `changeOwnership` and `renounceOwnership` functions), so we're really talking about two different things when we talk about OpenZeppelin's `owner` and the data in the actual blockchain, which will always be the deployer.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The contract's deployer address is stored in a variable called msg.sender. You can simply assign msg.sender to any variable or use it directly.

Comment: Yes i know what is msg.sender. Let's suppose i do not store this information during constructor. Can i access to contract's owner later by another way ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but `msg.sender` is generally whoever calls the contract, not the deployer. Did I misunderstand you?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. This is not an exact answer but it might help.

Following is an image from etherscan:
[image]

In the picture it is showing a transaction named `contract creation` where from address is specified.

Comment: That is true but how can i access to this information from a solidity contract or from on offchain javascript file ?

Comment: I have tried this but you can explore transaction logs, if possible, from web3.js.

Answer (score 0):

Using etherscan.io, there are multiple ways one can easily get the contract owner.

[image: image from etherscan.io]

1- In the above image you can see **CONTRACT CREATOR**, in the middle tile, is the owner of the contract. Copy the following link and just add your contract add to it:
https://etherscan.io/address/contract_address

2- If the contract is verified, can check from the code

3- You can also get the deployer/owner from etherscan API:

https://api.etherscan.io/api
?module=contract
&action=getcontractcreation
&contractaddresses=CONTRACT_ADDRESS&apikey=YOUR_API_KEY

Note: You can pass comma separeted multiple contract addresses.